# Join query based using Case or If

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a transaction table ( includes all transactions ), buyer table ( includes buyer's id, name and other details ), seller table ( includes seller's id, name and other details )

In transaction table that there are two columns user id ( corresponding seller or buyer id ) and user flag ( has one of two values - 'buyer' or 'seller' ).

I want to know the user name from buyer or seller table depending on the user flag and user id. I have tried using following query, but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT trans.* 
FROM transaction_summary AS trans 
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT * FROM CASE WHEN trans.user_flag = 'buyer' THEN Buyer ELSE Seller END AS users) 
ON users.id = trans.user_id 
ORDER BY transaction_id desc
```

Comment: Do buyers and sellers really need separate tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select t.*,
       case when trans.user_flag = 'buyer' 
            then (select name from buyers where id = t.user_id)
            else (select name from seller where id = t.user_id)
       end as name
from transactions t
```

Comment: @gauri If answer helped, you should accept it (green check mark on the left) and optionally upvote.

Answer (score 0):

You can not join dynamically. Join both tables and select the value with a `case`

```
SELECT trans.*, 
       case when trans.user_flag = 'buyer' 
            then b.name
            else s.name
       end as name
FROM transaction_summary trans 
LEFT JOIN Buyer b on b.id = trans.user_id
LEFT JOIN Seller s on s.id = trans.user_id
ORDER BY transaction_id desc
```